# Why can't I create a std::string_view from std::string iterators?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring, string-view

It is possible to create a `std::string_view` from a `std::string` easily. But if I want to create a string view of a range of `std::string` using the iterators of the `std::string` does not work.

Here is the code that I tried: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xrodd8PMq

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string str{"My String"};
    std::string_view strView{str};  // works
    //std::string_view strSubView{str.begin(), str.begin() + 2}; // error
}
```

Of course maybe we can make the substring out from `str` and use to make a string view `strSubView`, but there is an extra string creation.

I found that the `std::basic_string_view` s fifth constructor takes the range of iterators.

```
template<class It, class End>
constexpr basic_string_view(It first, End last);
```

But is it only the iterators of the `std::string` or just  `std::basic_string_view` 's itself? If not for `std::string`'s iterates why shouldn't be we have one, after all the string view:

> describes an object that can refer to a constant contiguous sequence
> of char-like objects !

Taking the range of contiguous sequence of char, should not we count?

Comment: That constructor is added in C++20. If you are compiling with a C++17 compiler then it isn't present. [It works if you target C++20](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7K3W5b7bb)

Comment: _"we can make the substring out from str... but there is an extra string creation."_ `std::string_view` [can create substrings too](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/substr).  `strSubView = strView.substr( 0, 2 );`. That would be comparable to what you are attempting.

Comment: @Caleth Oh yes, that was just under my eye, but I didn't notice the language tag in cppreference. That means in C++17 there is no way to do it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[That constructor is added in C++20](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7K3W5b7bb). If you are compiling with a C++17 compiler then it isn't present.

You can write a function that does the same thing

```
std::string_view range_to_view(std::string::iterator first, std::string::iterator last) {
    return first != last ? { first.operator->(), last - first } : { nullptr, 0 };
}
```

Comment: I hope the std::string_view  will be moce constructed where ever I call the  `range_to_view` ?

Comment: @Const it's an unmaterialised temporary, it gets constructed in place at the call site

Comment: In case if `first` points to end, the `operator->` will fail

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko no, you'll get a pointer one past the end

Answer (score 4):

> Why can not I create a std::string_view from std::string itertors?

You can, but only since C++20.

> But is it only the iterators of the std::string or just std::basic_string_view 's itself?

It's any contiguous iterators of appropriate value type. Both string and string view iterators are accepted. The exact constraints are listed in the documentation.

> That means in C++17 there is no way to do it??

There's no way to use a constructor that doesn't exist, but there are several ways of getting the string view that you want. Here's one:

```
std::string_view strSubView = strView.substr(0, 2);
```

or without the intermediate variable:

```
std::string_view strSubView = std::string_view{str}.substr(0, 2);
```

or if you only have those iterators and have no way of accessing the string:

```
std::string_view strSubView {&*first, last - first};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I prefer a helper function rather until I am able to use C++20.

Comment: `&*first` may crash if `first` points to `end`

Comment: `&*first` is the same as `first.operator->()`  in  Caleth's answer, right?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Effectively yes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as it is not safe to dereference the iterator (i.e. calling to `operator*` and `operator->` on iterator that points to end can crash your app), the only way in C++17 I see is to call `string_view::substr()` and use iterators only to calculate the size and index.

```cpp
constexpr std::string_view make_string_view(std::string_view str, 
                                            std::string_view::iterator first, 
                                            std::string_view::iterator last) noexcept
{
    return str.substr(first - str.begin(), last - first);
}
```

And for `std:string` use `std::string::data()` as initial pointer.

```cpp
std::string_view make_string_view(std::string const& str, 
                                  std::string::const_iterator first, 
                                  std::string::const_iterator last) noexcept
{
    return std::string_view(str.data() + (first - str.begin()), last - first);
}
```